# Are there anything wrong in the following proofs

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Problem 1**
>
> Let $\left(S,\circ\right)$ be a semigroup. If for any $a$ and $b$ the equations $a\circ x=b$ and $y\circ a=b$ has a solution then show that $\left(S,\circ\right)$ is a group.
>
> ***Proof***
>
> We use the following definition of a group.
>
> > A binary structure $\left(G,\circ\right)$ is said to be a group if,
> >
> > 1. $(a\circ b)\circ c=a \circ (b\circ c)\ \ \forall a,b,c\in G$
> > 2. $\exists e \in G \mid e\circ x=x \ \ \forall x\in G$
> > 3. $\exists z \in G \mid z\circ a=e \ \ \forall a\in G$
>
> $ \exists x,y\in S \mid(a \circ x=b) \land (y \circ a=a)\implies y\circ (a \circ x)=y\circ b \implies (y \circ a)\circ x=y\circ b \implies a \circ x=y\circ b \implies b=y \circ b$
>
> This shows that the same $y$ which satisfies the equation $y \circ a=a$ also satisfies $y \circ b=b$ for all $a, b \in S$. Hence (2.) is satisfied.
>
> Now we call this element $y$ by $e$ and find the solution of $z \circ a=y$. Since by problem such a $z$ always exists, (3.) is also satisfied.
>
> Hence $(S, \circ)$ is a group.
>
> **Problem 2**
>
> $H\leq G \iff a\circ b^{-1} \in H\ \ \forall a,b \in H$
>
> ***Proof***
>
> Now the part $H\leq G \implies a\circ b^{-1} \in H\ \ \forall a,b \in H$ is trivial since $H \leq G$ implies that there is a unique solution of the equation $x \circ b=a\ \ \forall a,b \in H$ and hence the proof is skipped. Only the proof of the second part is discussed below.
>
> To prove closure in $H$ first of all we prove the existence of identity.
>
> > $a\circ b^{-1} \in H \implies a\circ a^{-1} \in H \implies e\in H$
>
> Notice that this is the same $e$ of $G$. Hence existence of identity is confirmed.
>
> Then $a,e \in H \implies e \circ a^{-1} \left(=a^{-1}\right)\in H$ Thus existence of inverse is also confirmed. Thus $a,b \in H \implies a,b^{-1} \in H \implies a\circ b \in H$. Hence closure is also established.
>
> The thing that remains to be shown is associativity. $a,b,c \in H\implies a,b,c \in G \implies (a\circ b) \circ c=a \circ (b \circ c)$
>
> Hence the result is proved.

Are there anything that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof for problem 1 works, but when you write

> $ \exists x,y\in S \mid(a \circ x=b) \land (y \circ a=a)\implies y\circ (a \circ x)=y\circ b \implies (y \circ a)\circ x=y\circ b \implies a \circ x=y\circ b \implies b=y \circ b$

you should quantify $a$ and $b$, e.g. "$\forall a,b \in S, \exists x,y\in S ~\mid$ ..."

In problem 2, the reverse implication is false if $H$ is the empty set, so there is no proof for the problem as stated. This shows up in your proof when you write

> $\dots \implies a\circ a^{-1} \in H \implies \dots$

which assumes $\exists a \in H$.  If the problem is changed to ensure $H$ is not the empty set, your proof is fine.

Comment: If $H$ is an emptyset then it can't be a subgroup of the group $G$ since subgroup of a group is also a group and by the definition of a group it can't be empty.

Comment: @user170039 That's besides the point.  The empty set does satisfy the condition on the right side of $\iff$, but it does not satisfy the left side, which makes the question as written false.

Comment: @user170039: The claim in problem 2 is a double-implication. It's equivalent to the forward implication 

$H\le G ~~\implies~~ a\circ b^{-1} \in H ~~\forall a,b\in H$

and the backward implication

$a\circ b^{-1} \in H ~~\forall a,b\in H~~\implies~~H\le G$.

In the backward implication, $H$ is just a set, not a subgroup.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for clarifying.